# How do I add an integer to a char in Java?

Tags: java, char, encryption

I'm making a Cipher in Java but I can't do the follwing thing:
I want to edit the value of a char array to encrypt it

How should I do this?

Changing the ASCII value of each char might be the answer, I don't know; that's why I'm asking you Guys!

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to do with this cipher? If you're adding the same integer to each char in your array, this is roughly going to be as secure as a ROT-type cipher.

Comment: Thanks alot, I had already tried both of those things but for some reason it didn't work. Thanks, that was really fast

Comment: And by the way, the text is encrypted with a PIN code in the algorithm, this way tou have to use the same one when you decrypt as when you encrypt and if you use the wrong code the text will be even harder to decrypt, if not impossible!

Comment: Is you PIN the encryption key? How many characters? Something like 4 digits would be extremely weak.

Comment: With enough content (messages between you and your friends) any simple substitution cipher can be broken. All you have to do is follow the statistics of letter occurrences within the messages and compare them to the statistics of the language you are using.

Comment: The only theoretically impossible to break simple substitution cipher is the [vernon one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) cipher which uses a key that is just as long as the text message, it is randomly generated, and only you and your friends know the key / how to generate the next sequence of the key.

Comment: For example using the contents of a book you wrote as padding for all of your messages sent to your friends so long as only you and they have that book.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Hopefully, OP didn't write a book of random characters, but that's exactly what he **had** to write if he wants to use it as a one-time pad. Using a book would be almost as weak as using a short, random key.

Comment: @MihaiStancu A one-time pad with a properly generated and exchanged pad is (to my knowledge) the only form of encryption that can not be defeated with any form of attack on the message. Even by a quantum computer as any possible message of the same length can be generated based on the pad. I have written a few OTP programs but can never get anyone to use them with me as pad handling is such a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add an `int` to a `char`, but the result is an `int` - you'd have to cast back to `char` to put it back in the array, unless you use the compound assignment operator:

```
array[x] += someInt;
```

or

```
array[x] = (char) (array[x] + someInt);
```

However, usually this *isn't* an appropriate way of performing encryption. You'll often end up with unprintable characters, or characters which don't even have a specific meaning in Unicode. Instead, most encryption algorithms are designed to work on arbitrary *binary* data - i.e. byte arrays.

Usually you would convert the string into a byte array first (e.g. with `String.getBytes(charset)` - definitely specify an encoding). Then perform encryption on the byte array, giving you a new byte array. If you *really* need to convert it back to text, use base64 to do so - do *not* use `new String(encryptedBytes)`, as you no longer have text data encoded in a normal text encoding.

Comment: If he is working on a simple shift cipher such as the Caesar or Viginere though, which I suspect he is if he is starting out with ciphers, then his method of adding an int to a char is entirely appropriate is it not?  Obviously for more complex encryption it isn't.

Comment: @JonTaylor he should probably keep it in the printable range so he can easily interpret the results.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, `char` and `int` are compatible types so just add them with `+` operator.

```
char c = 'c';
int x = 10;
```

`c + x` results in an integer, so you need an *explicit casting* to assign it to your character varaible back.

```
c = (char)(c + x); // After this assignment, c = 'm'
```

Comment: Except that you won't be able to assign back into the `char[]` array without a cast...

Answer (score 0):

The simple symmetric rotation cipher uses the same function both to encode as well as to decode the data when using a 26 letter alphabet.

```
public class Rot13 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if       (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') c += 13;
            else if  (c >= 'A' && c <= 'M') c += 13;
            else if  (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') c -= 13;
            else if  (c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z') c -= 13;
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Source [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Rot13.java.html).

In the above example there is no need for the cast to `char` because of the "add and assign" operator that stores the result within the initial container (`char c`) which is a char.

Answer (score 0):

Add the int `value` with the char and typecast back to char as below:

```
  char a = 'a';
  char b = (char)(a+5);
  System.out.println(b);  //<-prints "f"
```

In char array,

```
     charArray[index] = (char)(charArray[index] + intValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public class IntPos {
    static int   dim = 4;
    public static String[][] main(){
        
      String[][] p = new String[dim][dim];  
      char letter = 'A';
      
      
      for(int i = 0; i < dim;i++){
         for(int j = 0; j<dim;j++){
             
            char newLetter =(char)(letter + i);
            p[i][j] = Character.toString(newLetter)+j;
            
            System.out.println(p[i][j]);
             
             
         } 
      }
      
        
      return p;  
    }
    
      
     
}
```